# How to use methods from one project in another project with Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have set up a project, which has a method that I want to use in another project. I tried adding the other project (the one that I want to get the method from) into my dependencies. However all this seems to have done is make so the errors in the text editing space disappear, but when I run the code I still get the errors that I would have gotten without adding the dependency.

The error report was pretty basic and just said that it can't find my symbols.

Also, the method that I want does autocomplete so clearly it is being detected, but for some reason just when I compile it does it encounter an error.

Comment: I didn't understand: your error is at compile time or at runtime?

Comment: Compile time. Intellij just has a run button that compiles and runs the code.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).